# Apply a condition on each element in several matrices

Tags: r

My question contains two parts.

Suppose I have two matrices such that:

```
> mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[3,]  0.4  0.5  0.0  0.0    0
[4,]  0.5  0.5  0.4  0.0    0
[5,]  0.5  0.5  0.4  0.7    0

> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[3,]  0.9  0.5  0.0  0.0    0
[4,]  0.5  0.5  0.4  0.0    0
[5,]  0.5  0.5  0.4  0.3    0

> mat <- list(mat1, mat2)
```

## First part

I would like to check if each corresponding values in both matrices are sum to `1` or not. if yes, then print the sum if not then return an error. Here is my try:

```
mat <- list(mat1, mat2)


myf <- function(mat){
  for(i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:5){
      if(all(Reduce('+', mat)) == 1 ){
        return(Reduce('+', mat))
      }else{
        stop("some of output are > 1")
      }
    }
  }
```

}
The output:

```
     Error in myf(family) : cann
In addition: Warning message:
In all(Reduce("+", mat)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

## Second part

I would like to check if any of the element of the matrices is `< 0`.

I tried this:

```
if(Reduce('|', lapply(family, '<', 0))){
```

stop("stop all sum must be positive")
}

The output is:

```
Warning message:
In if (Reduce("|", lapply(family, "<", 0))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

> 

Any help please?

Comment: Did you meant `(mat1 + mat2)== 1`  or if it is a `list` i.e. `Reduce('+', mat)==1`

Comment: yes, but I have large number of matrices and would like to check all that. `(mat1+mat2+..+mat10)`

Comment: In that case, place it in a `list` as you showed and use `Reduce('+', mat) == 1`

Comment: sorry, yes it is a list but.

Comment: Ok, I will have a try. And what about the second part. Thanks  a lot

Comment: The second part would be `Reduce('|', lapply(mat, '<', 0))`

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the first part and I got the same warning message.

Comment: `Warning message:
In if (Reduce("+", mat) == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: Based on your example, I am not getting any warning message.  I assume the matrices are of the same dimension.  Here, `mat <- list(mat1, mat2)`

Comment: yes, they are of the same dimension

Comment: Use `if(!all(Reduce("+", mat) == 1)){...}`

Comment: does not as well. I will clear my environment and see.

Comment: @akrun , sorry I need to check the sum of each two element. That is the sum of the first element of the mat1 and first element of mat2 and see if the sum is `=1` or not.

Comment: @tobiasegli_te I would like to check the sum of each corresponding elements and see if they are `=1` or not.

Comment: @Alice Yes, that is what the `Reduce` is doing i.e. it get the sum of each corresponding element. The output of `Reduce('+', mat)` will be the same as the output you got from the function

Comment: @Alive and if you want to check if this is the case for all elements in your matrix, than you should use `all()`, otherwise you will get the error `the condition has length > 1 ...`

Comment: @tobiasegli_te I update my question and function but does not give me back the error. I will try `all`. Thank you so much.

Comment: @akrun thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @akrun and @tobiasegli_te

```
myf <- function(mat){
      if(!all(Reduce('+', mat) <= 1 )){
        stop("some of output are > 1")
      }
}


             if(all(Reduce('|', lapply(mat, '<', 0)))){
             stop("stop all sum must be positive")
             }
```